# dynamic framework: how to hide the local symbols?

Tags: xcode, linker, clang, xcframework

I am building an .xcframework which contains an iphonesimulator and iphoneos frameworks. There is some Swift code, and some C++ code, which is linked into a shared object (*Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64*). I build my C++ with `-fvisibility=hidden`, and only the symbols that I explicitly mark, are exported. But, when I run `nm -gC`, I see all kinds of symbols that are still there – and they are visible even in the iOS app that is built using this framework. For example, I have an inner class `Secret` (it is only used in one **cpp** file). And `nm -gC` shows me (and all hackers out there)

```
00010292 t Secret::getString() const
```

Is there a way to hide this and other sensitive information?

And, on the other hand, how can I keep the auto-generated `_AlexSDKVersionNumber` exported?

Comment: This has no 'significant' size bearings. Is that right?

Comment: @mfaani no, the size implications are irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure your project settings correctly for Stripping to hide internal names.

Go to `Your target` > `Build Settings` > `Deployment`:

1. Set `Deployment Postprocessing` to `YES` to enable Stripping.
2. Set `Strip Style` to `Non-Global Symbols`.

Now `nm` should provide global (external) symbols only for your binary.

Comment: Thanks, this works. `DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING = YES;` it is.

Answer (score 0):

As for keeping the auto-generated `_AlexSDKVersionNumber` exported, I came up with a not-so-dirty hack:

1. add a header file to my project, call it AlexSDK_vers.h:

   ```
   extern __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) const double AlexSDKVersionNumber;
   ```
2. in Build Settings, add `OTHER_CFLAGS=-include\${PWD}/AlexSDK/AlexSDK_vers.h`